# Why does GCC not vectorise, or accumulate sums in registers?

Tags: gcc, optimization, vectorization, matrix-multiplication, cpu-registers

GCC produces some pretty slow code for multiplying a matrix of size 8 x 250 by one of size 250 x 4.

```
#define MR 8
#define NR 4
#define KC 250

void matmul(double *a, double *b, double *c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MR; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NR; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < KC; k++) {
                c[i * NR + j] += a[i * KC + k] * b[k * NR + j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The hot loop in the assembly looks like

```
.L3:
        vmovsd  xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx]
        add     rax, 32
        add     rdx, 8
        vmulsd  xmm0, xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax-32]
        vaddsd  xmm1, xmm1, xmm0
        vmovsd  QWORD PTR [rcx], xmm1
        cmp     rax, rsi
        jne     .L3
```

We see there is no vectorisation, even though it should be possible to vectorise over j. The sum of k is also not accumulated in registers, instead written back to memory each time. Why can GCC not optimise this? We could write something like this for the inner-loop:

```
.L12:
        vmovupd ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi]
        vbroadcastsd    ymm10, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        add     rdi, 8
        add     rsi, 32
        vbroadcastsd    ymm9, QWORD PTR [rdi+1992]
        vfmadd231pd     ymm8, ymm0, ymm10
        vbroadcastsd    ymm10, QWORD PTR [rdi+3992]
        vfmadd231pd     ymm7, ymm0, ymm9
        vbroadcastsd    ymm9, QWORD PTR [rdi+5992]
        vfmadd231pd     ymm6, ymm0, ymm10
        vbroadcastsd    ymm10, QWORD PTR [rdi+7992]
        vfmadd231pd     ymm5, ymm0, ymm9
        vbroadcastsd    ymm9, QWORD PTR [rdi+9992]
        vfmadd231pd     ymm4, ymm0, ymm10
        vbroadcastsd    ymm10, QWORD PTR [rdi+11992]
        vfmadd231pd     ymm3, ymm0, ymm9
        vbroadcastsd    ymm9, QWORD PTR [rdi+13992]
        vfmadd231pd     ymm2, ymm0, ymm10
        vfmadd231pd     ymm1, ymm0, ymm9
        cmp     rax, rdi
        jne     .L12
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/qrWKPPvaG) is the full version of the code GCC produces, as well as a version I want / expect it to produce.

The hand-written one is 5 times faster on my zen2 processor. Clang does vectorise, but also does some weird stuff that makes it 2x slower than GCC.

Comment: Your link shows the clang output and not the gcc output. Also, could you [edit] your question to show some relevant parts (input code, the parts of the output you care about) in your question? Relying on external links for essential information is discouraged (as it can cause the question to age poorly due to bitrot, among other reasons).

Comment: Optimization is *hard*. Doing it automatically in a compiler doubly so. While the compilers optimizations are better than most people can do in close to 99% of all cases, there's still that around one-percent where it makes more sense to hand-optimize. If the compiler have hints in the form of attributes or pragmas it could help as well with the automatic optimizations.

Comment: Also, the source code, its flow and how it's structured could also help the compiler make better optimizations, Reordering code, or structure it differently, or reordering or structure data, could make a lot of difference in the generated code.

Comment: Does `restrict` help in any way?